# Is mysql data safe with htaccess?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a login page for my website. In the php script of this page, I have connection.inc which includes mysql connection data. I am aware that this is not secure as anyone can access it by going to www.example.com/connection.inc.

I have added .htacess to the root folder with

```
<Files ~ "\.inc$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>
```

in it.

Now when i go to www.example.com/connection.inc it now comes up with error 403:forbidden.

Is this now highly secured. i.e can no-one now access this information?

Comment: why are you using the `inc` extension?

Answer (score 2):

If you changed the extension from `.inc` to `.php` then you have less risk.  If they access the `connection.php` file from the browser, they will just get served a blank page.

If someone accidentally deletes the .htaccess file, or it became inactive for some reason, it no longer will deny access to the file.

On the flip side, the same can happen with PHP.  If someone messes up the server configuration and `.php` files aren't handled by the PHP engine, they will be output usually as text or octet/stream and the full source will be served.

Bottom line, you are probably safe using your .htaccess method, but if you can, just change the extension to .php and then you can skip the .htaccess for that completely.  You can still include the `connection.php` just as you do the `.inc`.

Also, your MySQL user is probably only allowed to connect to the server from localhost.  If that is the case, even if I knew your username and password, I couldn't connect because I am not coming from the right host.  Additionally, it is possible that MySQL is not listening for connections on all addresses, and possibly only on localhost, but that depends on how it is set up.

Comment: thank you. is this correct? In login php i put include('connection.php'); then in connection.php i put <?php include('connection.inc') ?>...

Comment: Just copy the contents from connection.inc into connection.php and delete connection.inc.  .inc was used in very old versions of PHP.  Now it is more standard to just put your data in .php files and include them instead of using .inc.

Comment: I understand now. You can get software to read php source code which is why I think .inc is more secure do you not agree?

Comment: Well, I think .inc is less secure because that is plain text.  What do you mean by "software to read php source code"?  Do you mean it can read it from a remote server?  That is not possible.  If software could read PHP source code, I don't see why it couldn't read the .inc file.

Comment: Jacob, Snippets is irrelevant to this discussion.  Apache/IIS/... will typically pass any php to the PHP runtime system which will execute it, not send it to the end-user. What the user sees is any _output_ it produces.  Even so, I have a convention which I implement with a filter which forbids URI access to any file or directory starting with "." or "_".

Comment: That can't read the source code from remote servers, you have to install it on the local server, and then all it does is read files and do syntax highlight using PHP's `highlight_string()` function.  If someone is able to get into your server and install that, then they can already view your source other ways.